# PHP & Imagemagik: get image list of converted images from PDF

Tags: php, pdf, image-processing, imagemagick

Im using Imagemagik and Ghostscript libraries in order to convert a multiple-paged PDF document into .jpg images I'm running the following command:

exec('convert -density 72 -alpha Off "'.$pdf_file.'" -colorspace sRGB -antialias "'.$save_to.'"', $output, $return_var);

Everything goes fine and after a while a list of .jpg images is created.

Now I would like to get access to that list as an array

Is there a native method of Imagemagik or Ghostwrite that can return the array of converted images?

Thank You, Fabio.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to save all the extracted images in an empty directory, and then use [`opendir()`](http://php.net/opendir) and [`readdir()`](http://php.net/readdir) to scan the list of files and put them into an array.